# Rails & Puma Server Start Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puma

I am receiving the following error when running the `rails s` command using Puma.

**Here is my error log:**

```
`➜  AdminInterface git:(master) ✗ rails s
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 4.2.6 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run 'rails server -h' for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[76311] Puma starting in cluster mode...
[76311] * Version 3.4.0 (ruby 2.3.0-p0), codename: Owl Bowl Brawl
[76311] * Min threads: 1, max threads: 6
[76311] * Environment: development
[76311] * Process workers: 1
[76311] * Phased restart available
[76311] * Listening on tcp://localhost:3000
[76311] Use Ctrl-C to stop
/Users/Paradise/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/puma-3.4.0/lib/puma/runner.rb:103:in 'reopen': No such file or directory @ rb_io_reopen - /Users/Paradise/Documents/Dev/salon-spa-pass/AdminInterface/shared/log/puma.stdout.log (Errno::ENOENT)
    from /Users/Paradise/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/puma-3.4.0/lib/puma/runner.rb:103:in 'redirect_io'
    from /Users/Paradise/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/puma-3.4.0/lib/puma/cluster.rb:40:in 'redirect_io'
    from /Users/Paradise/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/puma-3.4.0/lib/puma/cluster.rb:414:in 'run'
    from /Users/Paradise/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/puma-3.4.0/lib/puma/launcher.rb:172:in 'run'
    from /Users/Paradise/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/puma-3.4.0/lib/rack/handler/puma.rb:51:in 'run'
    from /Users/Paradise/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:286:in 'start'
    from /Users/Paradise/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in 'start'
    from /Users/Paradise/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in 'block in server'
    from /Users/Paradise/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in 'tap'
    from /Users/Paradise/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in 'server'
    from /Users/Paradise/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in 'run_command!'
    from /Users/Paradise/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in '<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in 'require'
    from bin/rails:4:in '<main>'
```

Comment: It's complaining that `/Users/Paradise/Documents/Dev/salon-spa-pass/AdminInterface/shared/log/puma.stdout.log` is not found.  On a unix/linux/Mac OS X system, that could mean that the process (or its user) doesn't have permissions to that file.  Check that the file does exist and that the permissions are set properly.

Comment: Can i just add the shared folder, log folder, and blank puma.stdout.log file?

Comment: @MichaelGaskill adding the folders and log file worked! Thank you. Can you add this as your answer and I will upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puma is complaining that `/Users/Paradise/Documents/Dev/salon-spa-pass/AdminInterface/shared/log/puma.std‌​out.log` is not found. On a unix/linux/Mac OS X system, that could mean that the process (or its user) doesn't have permissions to that file.

Check that the file does exist and that the permissions are set properly.  If the file does not exist, you can do something like this on Unix systems to create the folders in the path and a blank file:

```
mkdir -p /Users/Paradise/Documents/Dev/salon-spa-pass/AdminInterface/shared/log/ && touch /Users/Paradise/Documents/Dev/salon-spa-pass/AdminInterface/shared/log/puma.std‌​out.log
```

This will ensure that the file is created properly.  Be sure to verify your file permissions again after you do this.